# Mounting Shelving on Basement Wall with Plastic Moisture Barrier Sheeting

Tags: basement, waterproofing, mounting

So I have an older home, built in the 60s, and recently had the basement waterproofed. The company that did the waterproofing installed plastic sheeting vapor barrier on all the walls. They also installed a drain system around the perimeter of the basement

Here's a picture of what the walls look like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vuge.jpg

I want to mount shelves onto the wall, and I am wondering if I can drill through the vapor barrier into the cinder block, or will this cause issues with the waterproofing?

Answer (score 1):

I would not put any holes in it, this would likely increase the risk of water penetrating.

I would suggest putting up a framed wall with 2x4s along the edge. You would be able to put up sheetrock if you wanted, as well as shelves.  You can also mount the outlets on that, instead of dangling from the ceiling like it is now.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the company that did the water proofing and ask for their advice.